# POST method not working in Heroku with MongoDB / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, heroku

**I am deploying an small app that was working with my localhost but now on Heroku i am getting some problems with the GET and POST methods.
I have tried investigating for several hours but haven't found the correct answer yet.**

**// My index.js file**

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  path = require('path'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose');

let db = mongoose.connection,
port = 4000;

let server = app.listen(port, _server());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error de conexión: '));

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Base de datos conectada correctamente');
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

const tareas = require('./componentes/tareas/tareas.route');

app.use('/api', tareas);

module.exports = app;

function _server() {
  console.log('Back-end corriendo en el puerto ' + port);
};
```

**// My tareas.route.js**

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const tareas_api = require('./tareas.api');


router.param('tarea_id', function (req, res, next, tarea_id) {
    req.body.tarea_id = tarea_id;
    next();
});

router.route('/registrar_tarea')
    .post(
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.registrar_tarea(req, res);
        }
    );

router.route('/listar_tareas')
    .get(
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.listar_tareas(req, res);
        }
    )

router.route('/eliminar_tarea')
    .post(
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.eliminar_tarea(req, res);
        }
    )

router.route('/buscar_tarea/:tarea_id')
    .get(
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.buscartarea_tareaid(req, res);
        }
    )


router.route('/actualizar_tarea')
    .post(
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.actualizar_tarea(req, res);
        }
    );

router.route('/cambiar_estado')
    .post(
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.cambiar_estado(req, res);
        }
    );

module.exports = router;
```

**// My frontend services**

```
let registrar_tarea = (pFecha, pNombre, pDescripcion, pPrioridad, pEncargado) => {
  let request = $.ajax({
    url: '/api/registrar_tarea',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      fecha: pFecha,
      nombre: pNombre,
      descripcion: pDescripcion,
      prioridad: pPrioridad,
      encargado: pEncargado,
      estado: "habilitado"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  });

  request.done(function (msg) {
    swal.fire({
        type: 'success',
        title: 'La tarea fue registrada',
        text: `Gracias por registrar la tarea. Nombre: ${pNombre}`
    }).then(function () {
        window.location = "/public/listar_tareas.html";
    });
  });

  request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    swal.fire({
      type: 'error',
      title: 'La tarea no pudo ser registrada',
      text: 'Ocurrió un error inesperado, por favor intente de nuevo'
    });
  });
};

let listar_tareas = () => {

  let lista_tareas = [];

  let request = $.ajax({
    url: '/api/listar_tareas',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    async : false
  });

  request.done(function (res) {
   lista_tareas = res.tareas;
  });

  request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

  });
  return lista_tareas;

};
```

> This is the result: Cannot POST /api/registrar_tarea

Comment: Have you defined `registrar_tarea` route? Please share the code of `tareas.route`.

Comment: Hi Shubham, please see updated from the original post. Thanks

Comment: Are you running frontend and backend on same server? In url you should provide the complete url like `http://someURL//api/registrar_tarea` not the endpoint of API

Comment: See my answer below I hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the follow up Shubham, I tried everything you mention and didn't work. Shared the link to the GitHub repository in the original post in case someone is willing double check it :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I integrated Cloudinary but I forgot to add environment variables to heroku. Whoever has this issue, make sure checking the env variables

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using same url for different HTTP verbs,  You need to declare routes like this:

```
router.post('/registrar_tarea',
        function (req, res) {
            tareas_api.registrar_tarea(req, res);
        }
    )
```

Comment: Tried and didn't work. Updated my original post with the GitHub repository code, in case someone is willing to look it up. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is probably a noob error, but I was trying to deploy front end and back end in Heroku and that whats why I wasn't seeing anything in the front end.

Basically found the answer below:

https://fabiofranchino.com/blog/how-to-deploy-webapp-heroku-netlify/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that the MongoDB database did not have any whitelisted IPs.

To add a white listed IP, go to your MongoDB atlas clusters

Click on "network access" from the panel on the left.

Click on the "Add IP address" button, found on the right

Add your application IP, or add 0.0.0.0/0 to allow access from everywhere.